# variable in variable in batch and delayed expansion

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use variable in variable in conjunction with delayed expansion but still no luck.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET ERROR_COMMAND=exit /B ^!ERRORLEVEL^!
```

This is my last try. I want to setup an ERROR_COMMAND to be called when one of the steps in batch file crashes. The command is supposed to be:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 !ERROR_COMMAND!
```

or

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 %ERROR_COMMAND%
```

The thing is, I'm not able to find out, how to SET properly the ERROR_COMMAND variable, so that ERRORLEVEL is not evaluated at the time of assignment, but at the time of evaluating the variable

Of course I can copy&paste the code all over the batch file, but using the variable just seems a bit prettier...

Anyone?

Thanks, Milan

Comment: exit /B does not do what you think it does, foo.cmd&&onlyDoThisOnSuccess.cmd will not work

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, here are two:

A)

```
SET ERROR_COMMAND=call echo.errlvl=%%ERRORLEVEL%%

verify failthis 2>nul
%ERROR_COMMAND%
```

B)

```
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&set "X=!"
call (endlocal&set "ERROR_COMMAND=echo.errlvl=%X%ERRORLEVEL%X%")&setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

verify failthis 2>nul
%ERROR_COMMAND%
```

---

It should also be noted that if someone does set ERRORLEVEL=foo (In your script or "globally"), %ERRORLEVEL% will not resolve correctly (Same goes for %CD% and all the other built in special variables)

Comment: tricky one :) - for now i used goto instead of expading ERRORLEVEL in another variable

gonna test yours tomorrow and let you know

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: What is there to explain? It prints "errlvl=1" since the verify command fails (on purpose to show a >0 errorlevel) and %% is to prevent it from expanding %ERRORLEVEL% in the set command...